# Simplifying a Stochastic Integral to a Summation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I am writing my undergraduate dissertation on Self-Exciting Processes where the conditional intensity function is expressed as:
$$\lambda_t | \mathcal{H}_t = \lambda_0 + \int_0^t \phi(t-s)dN_s = \lambda_0 + \sum_{T_i \leq t}^{} \phi(t - T_i),$$
for function $\phi: {R_+} \to {R_+}$.
My question is how did we go from the stochastic integral with respect to the point process (N_s) to the summation? The books I have checked do not explain this transition. Thank you :)

Comment: Hint: counting measure.

Comment: Perhaps is it because $d N_s = 0$ if there is no count, and $d N_s =1 $ when there is a count. So the integral with respect to $N_s$ takes into account all $\phi$ kernel functions which occurred at [0,t], which essentially counts al kernel functions for all $i$ such that $T_i \leq t$. Is this intuition correct?